# How do I delete a record in a same table (use WHERE EXIST or INNER JOIN)?

Tags: sql, database, qsqlquery

I have 2 tables (product and sales_tran) it has 2 matching columns which is product_name. I try to use INNER JOIN to delete a matching record in a same table but hit an error
Could you help to advise on my query below? I would like to delete the record

```
DELETE FROM product
INNER JOIN sales_tran ON product.product_name = sales_tran.product_name ;
```

Comment: Mysql or sql server ?

Answer (score 0):

In nysql
you can delete all rows, that have a relation to sales_tran

```
DELETE product FROM product p
INNER JOIN sales_tran st ON p.product_name = st.product_name ;
```

In sql Server it looks the same

```
DELETE p
FROM product p
INNER JOIN sales_tran st
  ON p.product_name = st.product_name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL specify alias for the table from which you want to delete

```
DELETE p
FROM product p
INNER JOIN sales_tran s ON p.product_name = s.product_name ;
```

Or you can use a sub query

```
delete 
from product
where product_name in (
    select product_name 
    from sales_tran 
)
```